# Several Multitenant Rails Apps using the same Redis server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

**Scenario:**

We have several Multitenant applications that use Sidekiq and Redis.

In each Rails application, we have several accounts. Each account works independently of the other accounts. Each account corresponds to a different client.

For a matter of costs and infrastructure maintenance, we want to use the same Redis server for all the applications. The traffic generated by our Multitentant applications (we have approximately 20 apps, with about 40 accounts) is not excessive for a single Redis server, and therefore our problem is only about configuring that server.

**Requirements**

We need to uniquely identify each queue of each application/account, so that when Sidekiq acts as a server it processes only its own queues.

The separation / identification could be done at different levels:

- Separating unequivocally by account
- Separating unequivocally by machine(application). Each machine(application) has an associated database and within that database account_id are unique. Each Job has an account_id identifier and therefore, knowing which machine (or database) a Job belongs to, we would automatically identify the account.

**Possible solutions**

1- Identify the accounts with a uuid. Each Account would have a uuid field that will be used to name the queues that this account would use in Sidekiq.

Pros: We could easily filter the queues by account, even in monitoring.
Cons: Many queues would be generated, so if we do not control the polling time to the Redis server we could have performance problems.

2- Use different databases. By Separating databases by machine(application) we would solve the problem of the uniqueness of accounts. The problem is that Redis by default accepts only 16 bbdd and also it numbers them from 0 to 15. So it would be very delicate handling (Manual?) Of these database ids.

3- Use namespaces. Disapproved by Mike Perham http://mikeperham.com/2015/09/24/storing-data-with-redis/
Namespaces can act as a separator per machine or per queue.

We would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your option 1 is the same as option 3, only you have to write all the code for key generation.

Comment: "Consider this for hobbyists only who only want to pay for a single Redis database from a SaaS" - so, that's you? :) If you want to share the same server, you don't really have a choice.

Comment: (disclosure: working for Redis Labs) my employer's SaaS offers are based on subscriptions for RAM usage, not the number of databases. Furthermore, unlike other providers, each database runs its own Redis server so no need to worry about namespacing and/or interblocks.

Comment: And if you want to run your own, the best way to achieve what you need is spinning up a redis-server per account, on the same or different physical/virtual hardware - depends on your sizing.

Comment: So did you find a solution? Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that Redis by default accepts only 16 bbdd and also it numbers them from 0 to 15. So it would be very delicate handling (Manual?) Of these database ids.

So, why use default? Set appropriate value for property `databases` in the conf file

```
127.0.0.1:6370> config get databases
```

> 1) "databases"
>   2) "65536"

Comment: 65536 is just a random number. The maximum is somewhere between 2147m and 214m. But at 214m it tries to allocate 12gb of memory on empty db (and fails on my machine with 8). So if you go for really high amounts, check that performance and memory profile matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we use both first and second choices. We are using only one Redis server with an uid for the queues and different databases to ensure that the jobs are not been taken by a wrong machine.